# SQL Server Analysis Services and Team Foundation Server

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssas, sql-server-2008-r2

I am attempting to setup Team Foundation server, however I am running into a problem regarding SQL Server Analysis Services.

The installer gives a warning saying that Analysis Services is not running.  Analysis Services was installed when we installed the version of SQL because we do have the Deployment Wizard etc, however there is not a service showing in the services window that is running.

I tried to run the deployment wizard but it wants me to specify what database to connect to, and I can't create a database because I cant connect to analysis services.

There appears to be something fundamental that I am missing here, if anyone could give me guidance I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD account you install and configure TFS 2010 with has to have administrative privileges in the AS cube.  You should be able to connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio.  It needs these privileges during configuration to create and setup the cube.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install SQL?  Try tossing the SQL Install disc back in and install Analysis Services if it's not already present.

If you installed SQL Express as part of the TFS Install, then you don't get Analysis Services or any TFS features that depend on it (reporting).

Comment: Actually the server is managed by a hosting company that installs SQL for us.  It is SQL Full, and I have called them and they claim that Analysis services is installed, yet I can not see it in the services.